# передать @IntDef тип из одной активити в другую

Tags: android, android-intent, android-parcelable, android-annotations

Столкнулся с такой задачей, что необходимо получить в одной активити `@IntDef` тип переменной, передать её в другую активити через `onActivityResult()`.

Проблема заключается в том, что к этой аннотации невозможно применить явное приведение, её нельзя сериализовать. Если создать поле с геттер\сеттерами, то при передаче возвращается `int`(в лучшем случае, иногда натыкаешься и на `String`).

`int` к `@IntDef` не применим - ибо это основной принцип и вся соль его использования.

Скажем, имеется некий `@IntDef`:

```
import android.support.annotation.IntDef;

@IntDef({Importance.noMatter, Importance.green, Importance.yellow, Importance.red})
public @interface Importance {

    public static int noMatter = 0;
    public static int green = 1;
    public static int yellow = 2;
    public static int red = 3;
}
```

Тогда, чтобы его использовать, достаточно написать `@Importance.green` - и нужный `int` перейдет во входной параметр, который ожидает, например - метод.

В случае, если мы используем просто цифру - компилятор этого сделать нам не позволит. И еще он нам не позволит сделать следующую конструкцию:

```
 private Importance importance;

    public Importance getImportance() {
        return importance;
    }

    public void setImportance(Importance importance) {
        this.importance = importance;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == EDITING_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

               String importanceString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("importance");

                switch (importanceString){
                    case "no_matter":
                        setImportance(Importance.noMatter);
                          break;

                }
```

Таким образом встает 2 варианта: либо искусственно сделать нечто подобное, сетуя на добропорядочность других разработчиков, либо как-то решить этот тупик.

Конечно, первый вариант быстрее, но всё-же хочу знать, сталкивался ли кто с подобным, или может я где-то что-то упустил\не увидел\недопонял, и на самом деле там есть простой механизм для подобного?

Если `Enum` можно хотя-бы сериализовать как объект, то здесь ума не приложу.

Как говорит мой хороший друг - идти по пути самурая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте такие параметры в методы помечая их тип аннотацией. Поместить их в `Bundle` можно обычным способом:

```
public static Intent newIntent(@Importance int importance) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Importance", importance);
    return intent;
}
```

Вытаскивая сериализованную переменную надо отметить тип оной также аннотацией + добавить коммент чтобы не ругался lint:

```
//noinspection ResourceType
@Importance
int importance = getIntent().getIntExtra("Importance", Importance.noMatter);
```

Comment: А сеттер как к полю сделать возможно?

Comment: По идея так же как в методе в ответе. Укажите аннотацией тип параметра и тип поля

Comment: не получается, иначе не спрашивал бы.

Comment: он ругается, что передаю инт, а он ожидает тип аннотации.Просто получается, что я не могу его вытащить за пределы `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Т.е вот так не выйдет? `@Importance
int importance; public void setImportance(@Importance int importance) {this.importance = importance}`? Я не очень вашу проблему пока что понял. Попробуйте отдельный вопрос задать

Comment: Именно, не выйдет.

Comment: я пока костыль написал, попозже задам.

Comment: @Asgard, а почему не выходит? На что ругается?

Comment: ругается, что ожидает тип `Importance`, а передаю ему `int`

Comment: @Asgard, А вы как передаёте? `setImporatance(Importance.noMatter)`?

Comment: по всякому, и так в том числе.
Кажется я понял, в чем ошибка: нужно хранить не Importance экземпляр, а `@Importance int a;` то есть нужно хранить простую инту с аннотацией. Еще не пробовал, но думаю сработает.

Comment: @Asgard, да, по идее так и надо